# Constraints on SUM function in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mysql-error-1111

I'm working on developing a basic search engine in MySQL. the search is based on keywords, and each searchable item has a number of keywords associated with it. Each keyword has a weight associated with it, to determine how "Important" the keyword is for the item. The tables look like this:

```
== table: keyword_item ==      
column: item_id (int)
column: keyword (varchar)
column: weight (float)

== table: item ==
column: id (int)
column: title (varchar)
column: url (varchar)
```

What I want to do is filter out items that has a large anough sum of weights, and I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT item_id, title, url, sum(weight) as w FROM keyword_item INNER JOIN item ON (w > 3 AND (keyword = 'key1' OR keyword = 'key2' OR keyword = 'key3' ) AND item_id = id) GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY w DESC
```

But that gives me the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'w' in 'on clause'
```

I also tried changing the "w > 3" in the ON clause to "sum(weight) > 3", but then that gives me the error:

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Now, I don't really know much about MySQL, and I'm sure there is a perfectly good explanation as to why this isn't working, but I would like to know whether there is a way to achieve what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses instead of putting everything in the `ON`.

```
SELECT item_id, title, url, sum(weight) as w
FROM keyword_item INNER JOIN item ON item_id = id
WHERE (keyword = 'key1' OR keyword = 'key2' OR keyword = 'key3')
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING w > 3
ORDER BY w DESC
```

Comment: Edit: sorry, I made a mistake when trying your query, it is working perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HAVING`:

```
SELECT item_id, title, url, sum(weight) as w 
FROM keyword_item 
INNER JOIN item ON item_id = id
WHERE  keyword in ('key1', 'key2', 'key3' )
GROUP BY item_id, title, url
HAVING sum(weight) > 3 
ORDER BY w DESC
```

Comment: Still leaves `w` in the `ON` clause, which is causing the error to begin with. I don't think you can use the result of aggregate function in a join clause, as the aggregate can't be computed until AFTER all the joins are completed. This is a chicken/egg problem.